# conflict between scrbook and dynkin-diagrams

Tags: koma-script, incompatibility, etoolbox, scrbook, dynkin-diagrams

I find a strange conflict between `scrbook` and `dynkin-diagrams`, here is the code

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams} 
\begin{document} 
\chapter{One}
Here is one \dynkin A2
\end{document}
```

An error message "Command \do undefined." is showing.

However, if I use

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams} 
\begin{document} 
Here is one \dynkin A2
\end{document}
```

Then it works.

**I wonder what cause it and how to fix this bug?**

Comment: In the code for `\chapter`, it seems `scrbook` is setting the definition of `\do` to `\relax` (put `\meaning\do` after `\chapter` then see what happens when you remove `\chapter`). The `\dynkin` command does `\renewcommand{\do}{...}` which throws an error because it expects `\do` to be defined.

Comment: I've [reported an issue to KOMA-Script](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/tickets/53/). In the discussion the KOMA-Script author states, that KOMA-Script's `tocbasic` is not the only package, that has `\let\do\relax` and shows an example with the same error without using KOMA-Script. So you should report the issue to the `dynkin-diagrams` maintainer (AFAIK to the email address in the sty file).

Comment: The issue seems to be fixed with [KOMA-Script 3.41.4057](https://komascript.de/current).

Answer (score 4):

The style file `dynkin-diagrams.sty` uses LaTeX's `\renewcommand` when it defines a temporary macro `\do` because it supposes that `\do` was defined already by previous macros. This is almost always a correct assumption but not when the `\chapter` macro from `scrbook.cls` is used. This macro re-defines `\do` and finally does `\let\do=\relax`. Then the following `\renewcommand\do` invoked from `\dynkin` fails.

It will be more correct if `dynkin-diagrams.sty` does `\def\do` and no `\renewcommand\do`, but we are not author of this macro file.

One obscure workaround should be as follows:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}
{\catcode`\@=11 \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\dynkin@save
   \expandafter{\dynkin@save \let\do=\LaTeX}} % :)
\begin{document} 
\chapter{One}
Here is one \dynkin A2
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is an incorrect way to cope with a command defined with `\NewDocumentCommand`.

Comment: No, this is an obscure way to modify this macro, as I mentioned in my answer :).

Comment: Not “obscure”, but wrong.

Comment: Not "wrong", but obscure.

Comment: Note, there is no simple correct solution, because the core of the problem is in the fact that some style files for LaTeX uses `\renewcommand` instead `\def` when they (re)define `\do` macro (designed by Knuth as a special temporary macro). The only correct solution is to replace all `\renewcommand\do` to `\def\do` in all LaTeX style files where is the wrong declaration.

Comment: I show a safer workaround, didn't you see it? Not invasive, using kernel features of LaTeX. Your workaround adds code in an unexpected place that could do harm.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE 2023-05-20

The new release of `dynkin-diagrams` released on 2023-05-18 has fixed the issue, by prefixing every usage of `\renewcommand{\do}[1]{...}` by `\providecommand{\do}{}`.

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

For historical reasons, at the start of a document (that is, after `\begin{document}` is processed), `\do` has the meaning `\noexpand`.

There have been discussions about removing this “hidden feature”, but it was thought that preserving this is important, because it has been so for about 30 years and packages *might* use it.

And indeed do, as you discovered. If you look in the documentation of `etoolbox`, you'll find several examples of

```
\renewcommand{\do}[1]{...}
```

and `dynkin-diagrams` makes extensive usage of `etoolbox` for list processing. It could dispense with it, by choosing `expl3` instead of mixing a few of it with `etoolbox` and `xstrings`.

As a consequence, no class or package should ever issue `\let\do\relax`, because, as far as `\renewcommand` is concerned, something equivalent to `\relax` is seen as undefined. Unfortunately, `scrbook` does it.

You can use a workaround. When starting a diagram, the package issues `\dynkin@save` and you can hook in it to provide a definition for `\do`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{dynkin-diagrams}

\AddToHook{cmd/dynkin@save/before}{\providecommand{\do}{}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
Here is one \dynkin A2
\end{document}
```

Comment: The version of the `dynkin-diagrams` package released on 2023/05/18 fixes the issue with no need to do patches.

Comment: Is expl3 preferable to etoolbox for list processing? Is xstrings a bad idea for a package to handle input strings?

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Definitely, I'd say.